# How to correctly setup Mobile Push with correct Contact Keys

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, contactbuilder

We use MC Email Studio (synced with the connector to Sales Cloud) to contact Subscribers via email and use the Salesforce `PersonContactId` as the Contact Key for all our sends.

We are implementing Mobile Push and have noticed MC created separate Contact records using the Device ID as the Contact Key, how can we avoid this and correctly associate devices to existing Contacts?

Answer (score 3):

You should understand that Mobile Push handles both Unknown and Identified mobile contacts.

First, start from your Use cases and decide if you want to target only Identified contacts or more widely also Unknown contacts (called also devices / app holders / mobile prospects).

After installing your mobile application and before logging into it, a contact is still unknown. You will have to choose if you want to have him in your MobilePush contact list.

If yes, intilializing the SDK will create a new mobile push contact with a random `GUID` generated automatically.

If no, you will have to delay Registration Until a Contact Key is set.

When this contact logs in your application, you will have to retrieve the `PersonContactId` and register it using the SDK.

If you choosed to have Unknown contacts, they will be converted into an identified contact after registration ( the `GUID` will be updated by `PersonContactId` for the same `Device ID`)

In order to retrieve the `PersonContactID`, I believe that you already have it as part of your authentication Service. If not, you will have to implement an API Call to the Salesforce Platform prior to registering the contact in MobilePush SDK.

Comment: Could we register the device with say a substitute ID and then set the correct ID in Marketing Cloud? The external system doesn't have any references to the PersonContactId, but we need to use this as the Contact Key in order to avoid duplication with the already created Contact with PersonContactId.

Comment: No you can't. You need to retrieve the PersonContactId from Salesforce. The substitute ID should be an External ID on the Person Account object.

Comment: We have those external IDs in Salesforce, the CRM system has a way to upsert using external IDs and attach the Salesforce ID but from what I know Marketing Cloud doesn’t have a feature like this?

Comment: Exactly. Marketing Cloud doesn't have this feature. You will need to call Salesforce first to retrieve the PersonContactID before registering to MobilePush. I have asked a similar question 2 years ago https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/181612/synchronisation-of-foreign-key-in-mobile-push-and-contact-key-in-contact-builder

Answer (score 2):

You handle contactkey registration within the SDK

iOS - '[Registration Updates Via Contact Key, Attributes, and Tags](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/user-data.html)'

Android - '[Registration Updates Via Contact Key, Attributes, and Tags](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/sdk-implementation/device-contact-registration.html)'

> You can configure the SDK in a mode that delays registration until a contact key is set by the application. Use this configuration mode only in implementations where the device running your app is tied to a specific contact key in Marketing Cloud and not to a generic device contact.